# jQuery Click event not getting triggered

Tags: jquery, ajax, dom, onclick

I am add a table to a plain HTML page after document ready using jQuery

The value that I get is a string of `"<table class=\"table table-hover\"><tr><th>Name</th><th>Father name.... <td><a class="deleteEmployee" href=\"#\" >Delete</a></td></tr> "`

jQuery method:

```
$(function () {
  $.ajax({
    url: "/Account/Report",
  }).done(function (callback) {
    $('#report').html(callback);
  });
});
```

I am able to bind the string withing a div #report but the following is not working.

```
$('.deleteEmployee').click(function () {
console.log('Clicked');
});
```

I thought that DOM might have not been updated but I am able to see the anchor element and table updated.

What am I missing out over here.

Comment: I can only assume that you need `$( document ).ready(function() {...});` around your click event based on the code provided.

Comment: @EternalHour its placed within the ready as you pointed out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to attach events to dynamically loaded content you have to attach the event to the document and use a selector like this:

```
$(document).on("click",".deleteEmployee",function(){
    console.log("Clicked");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can bind click method after ajax load is done ...

```
$(function () {
  $.ajax({
    url: "/Account/Report",
  }).done(function (callback) {
    $('#report').html(callback);

            $('.deleteEmployee').click(function () {
            console.log('Clicked');
            });

  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

load() which i like most... as above

```
$('#report').load("/Account/Report",function (callback) {

        $('.deleteEmployee').click(function () {
        console.log('Clicked');
        });
})
```